# react native expo is there a custom date time picker work on iOS and android

Tags: react-native, expo

I found a bunch of date time picker project on github, none of the work with expo. Or have to react-link which I can't because I'm in expo 100% js. Could be there a usable project somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

`react-native-modal-datetime-picker`
https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker

You can also find other expo compatible components at https://www.native.directory/

Answer (score 2):

Right now they recommend using [reaact-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker#basic-usage-with-state) It works quite well.

installation with

```
expo install @react-native-community/datetimepicker
```

Expo themselves don't have a lot in their documentation but you can find it here: [expo datetimepicker docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/date-time-picker/)

A very basic usage looks like this:

```
<DateTimePicker value={date}
                mode={mode}
                is24Hour={true}
                display="default"
                onChange={this.setDate} />
```

You can read a bunch more on this component in the readme file of the official component [docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker#getting-started).

Comment: It is a good choice and easy to use but, there are installation problems with it now. It works on a higher react version which is not supported by expo